# close a window in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I try to authenticate my web app using google app script .After authentication, the doGet function returns a HTML, I need to close the window using this HTML.

I tried using

```
window.onload = function() {
 window.open("","_self","").close();
};
```

and

```
window.onload = function() {
 window.close();
};
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can't close a window in Javascript if the window is not opened by the script that is trying to carry out the close operation.

The following snippet will work.

```
w = window.open('http://url');

//some operation or event calling

w.close();
```